# openlayers3 same style for selected features (only one changed property)?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have an ol3 layer with a style definition. I would like to use the same style for the select interaction:

```
style = function(feature, resolution) {

    var iconFont = 'FontAwesome';
    var iconFontText = '\uf1f8'; // fa-trash
    var iconSize = 24;
    var col = 'black';

    var styles = [];

    var styleIcon = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: 'Normal ' + iconSize + 'px ' + iconFont,
            text: iconFontText,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: col})
        })
    });
    styles.push(styleIcon);

    }

    return styles;
};

    new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: that.source,
            style: style
        });

    new ol.interaction.Select({
                features: that.selectedFeatures,
                style: style
            })
```

I only want to change one property (iconSize) of the style to highlight the selected features. Is that somehow possible? I do not want to define two seperate styles, but I would be ok if it was somwhow possible to programmatically copy the style and replace the iconsize value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I found a working solution:

You can add an additional argument (e.g. highlight [bool]) to the style function:

```
style = function(feature, resolution, highlight) {
...
}
```

and the instead of

```
new ol.interaction.Select({
                features: that.selectedFeatures,
                style: style
            })
```

you can use

```
new ol.interaction.Select({
                features: that.selectedFeatures,
                style: function(feature,resolution){
                     return style(feature,resolution,true);
                }
            })
```

Comment: Great solution. I've updated my fiddle including your solution.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution: Tell your function that `ol.interaction.Select` is active:

```
var style = function(ft, res, selecting){
  return [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#ffcc33',
        width: selecting ? 4 : 2
      })
    })
  ];
};

var selecting = false;
selectInteraction.on('select', function(evt) {
    selecting = evt.selected.length > 0;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/eepyne75/

Comment: I think this would then affect the unselected features as well since they share the same style... ?

Comment: Did you test the code? When unselected, the features come back to original style.

Comment: Yes I did. All feature icons change their style when one gets selected.

Comment: It only works until the features rerender. Try moving the map after you select a feature. This will trigger a refresh and all features adapt to the new styling rule.