# Creating map copies with different style function

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a vector map which I'd like to clone and style differently (and display side by side).

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: styleFunction
});
```

Ideally I'd like to create all those maps using a function with custom param which would be passed to the styleFunction. (After creating html element and building Map object together with layers). But e.g. style function expects only two params and it is not clear how I could pass another one.

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35199393/4640499).

Comment: @JonatasWalker cool it is exactly what I was looking for. This one could be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openlayers3 same style for selected features (only one changed property)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184546/openlayers3-same-style-for-selected-features-only-one-changed-property)